# Tic tac toe in JavaScript with minimax algorithm giving error maximum call stack size exceed

Tags: javascript, algorithm, tic-tac-toe, callstack, minimax

I am doing an assignment tic tac toe game. My minimax algorithm works fine on its own with an array and two players provided but when working with html collections of divs it gives an error of maximum call stack size exceed. I don't understand why it is happening. By searching google I know that my function somewhere calling itself over and over again but can't figure it out what to do solve this issue. I tried converting the .cells div collection into an array but still the same error occurred. Anybody please help me with this. 
Thank you.

```js
var humanPlayer, aiPlayer;
humanPlayer = 'x';
aiPlayer = 'o';
var cells = document.querySelectorAll(".cell");

/** Tic Tac Toe game object **/
var TicTacToe = {
  checkWinner : function(arr, player){
    if(
      (arr[0] === player && arr[1] === player && arr[2] === player)||
      (arr[3] === player && arr[4] === player && arr[5] === player)||
      (arr[6] === player && arr[7] === player && arr[8] === player)||
      (arr[0] === player && arr[3] === player && arr[6] === player)||
      (arr[1] === player && arr[4] === player && arr[7] === player)||
      (arr[2] === player && arr[5] === player && arr[8] === player)||
      (arr[0] === player && arr[4] === player && arr[8] === player)||
      (arr[2] === player && arr[4] === player && arr[6] === player)
    ){
      return true;
    }
    else{
      return false;
    }
  },//checkWinner function.

  getAvailableSpots : function(arr){
    var spots = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
      if(arr[i].textContent !== "x" && arr[i].textContent !== "o"){
        spots.push(i);
      }
    }
    return spots;
  },// getAvailableSpots function.

  minimax : function(newBoard, player){
    newBoard = Array.from(newBoard);
    var availSpots = this.getAvailableSpots(newBoard);
    if(this.checkWinner(newBoard, aiPlayer)){
      return {score: 10};
    }
    else if(this.checkWinner(newBoard, humanPlayer)){
      return {score: -10};
    }
    else if(availSpots.length === 0){
      return {score: 0};
    }

    var moves = [];

    for(var j = 0; j < availSpots.length; j++){
      var move = {};
      move.index = availSpots[j];
      newBoard[availSpots[j]] = player;
      if(player === aiPlayer){
        var result1 = this.minimax(newBoard, humanPlayer);
        move.score = result1.score;
      }
      else{
        var result2 = this.minimax(newBoard, aiPlayer);
        move.score = result2.score;
      }

      newBoard[availSpots[j]] = move.index;
      moves.push(move);
    }

    var bestMove;
    if(player === aiPlayer){
      var bestScore1 = -100000;
      for(var k = 0; k < moves.length; k++){
        if(moves[k].score > bestScore1){
          bestScore1 = moves[k].score;
          bestMove = k;
        }
      }
    }
    else{
      var bestScore2 = 100000;
      for(var l = 0; l < moves.length; l++){
        if(moves[l].score < bestScore2){
          bestScore2 = moves[l].score;
          bestMove = l;
        }
      }
    }

    return moves[bestMove];
  }// minimax function.


};//TicTacToe object literal.

function move(e){
  if(e.target.className === "cell" && e.target.textContent === ""){
    e.target.textContent = humanPlayer;
    var result = TicTacToe.minimax(cells, aiPlayer);
    cells[result.index].textContent = aiPlayer;
  }
}


document.querySelector('.cells').addEventListener('click', move);
```

```css
.*{
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.cells  {
  width: 390px;
  height: 390px;
  margin: 50px auto;
}

.cell {
  width:128px;
  height: 128px;
  border: 1px solid #dedede;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 128px;
  font-size: 80px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>

  <div class="cells">
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Stepping through your code in a debugger will almost certainly reveal the bug. If you're not familiar with the JS debuggers built into almost every browser nowadays, see e.g. [this tutorial](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/) (for Chrome, but other browsers have very similar debuggers).

Comment: "By searching google I know that my function somewhere calling itself over and over again" -> if it's your own code you should have noticed on your own. `TicTacToe.minimax` is being called recursively. Debugging is inded a good way of figuring out what's happening.

Comment: Tried debugging the code in the developer tools and it keep taking me back to where the minimax function is defined.  I am not sure whether it is the collection I am passing to the function is the problem or somewhere in the logic.

Comment: Well, yes, that's what you'd kind of expect to happen if the minimax function is being called several times. Have you tried putting a breakpoint at the beginning of the function and looking at the parameters passed to it (and the call stack) when it calls itself? You might notice something funny...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because your minmax function is recursive, meaning it tries every possible combination chain. To not repeat the same chain over and over, it creates a clone of the board on every recursion (via `Array.from(newBoard)`).

Now, back when you were testing it with primitve arrays, that copying of the board worked fine. However, now your board array is actually containing DOM objects, which will not be cloned by `Array.from()`. So your AI is basically altering the cells for every attempt which causes a stack overflow.

My suggestion would be to convert the current board to a primitive array before passing it to the minmax function.

```js
var humanPlayer, aiPlayer;
humanPlayer = 'x';
aiPlayer = 'o';
var cells = document.querySelectorAll(".cell");

/** Tic Tac Toe game object **/
var TicTacToe = {
  checkWinner : function(arr, player){
    if(
      (arr[0] === player && arr[1] === player && arr[2] === player)||
      (arr[3] === player && arr[4] === player && arr[5] === player)||
      (arr[6] === player && arr[7] === player && arr[8] === player)||
      (arr[0] === player && arr[3] === player && arr[6] === player)||
      (arr[1] === player && arr[4] === player && arr[7] === player)||
      (arr[2] === player && arr[5] === player && arr[8] === player)||
      (arr[0] === player && arr[4] === player && arr[8] === player)||
      (arr[2] === player && arr[4] === player && arr[6] === player)
    ){
      return true;
    }
    else{
      return false;
    }
  },//checkWinner function.

  getAvailableSpots : function(arr){
    var spots = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
      if(arr[i] !== "x" && arr[i] !== "o"){
        spots.push(i);
      }
    }
    return spots;
  },// getAvailableSpots function.

  minimax : function(newBoard, player){
    newBoard = Array.from(newBoard);
    var availSpots = this.getAvailableSpots(newBoard);
    if(this.checkWinner(newBoard, aiPlayer)){
      return {score: 10};
    }
    else if(this.checkWinner(newBoard, humanPlayer)){
      return {score: -10};
    }
    else if(availSpots.length === 0){
      return {score: 0};
    }

    var moves = [];

    for(var j = 0; j < availSpots.length; j++){
      var move = {};
      move.index = availSpots[j];
      newBoard[availSpots[j]] = player;
      if(player === aiPlayer){
        var result1 = this.minimax(newBoard, humanPlayer);
        move.score = result1.score;
      }
      else{
        var result2 = this.minimax(newBoard, aiPlayer);
        move.score = result2.score;
      }

      newBoard[availSpots[j]] = move.index;
      moves.push(move);
    }

    var bestMove;
    if(player === aiPlayer){
      var bestScore1 = -100000;
      for(var k = 0; k < moves.length; k++){
        if(moves[k].score > bestScore1){
          bestScore1 = moves[k].score;
          bestMove = k;
        }
      }
    }
    else{
      var bestScore2 = 100000;
      for(var l = 0; l < moves.length; l++){
        if(moves[l].score < bestScore2){
          bestScore2 = moves[l].score;
          bestMove = l;
        }
      }
    }

    return moves[bestMove];
  }// minimax function.


};//TicTacToe object literal.

function move(e){
  if(e.target.className === "cell" && e.target.textContent === ""){
    e.target.textContent = humanPlayer;
    var result = TicTacToe.minimax(domBoardToArray(cells), aiPlayer);
    cells[result.index].textContent = aiPlayer;
  }
}

function domBoardToArray(cells){
  return Array.prototype.slice.call(cells).map(function (cell){
    return cell.textContent
  })
}


document.querySelector('.cells').addEventListener('click', move);
```

```css
.*{
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.cells  {
  width: 390px;
  height: 390px;
  margin: 50px auto;
}

.cell {
  width:128px;
  height: 128px;
  border: 1px solid #dedede;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 128px;
  font-size: 80px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>

  <div class="cells">
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, really appreciate it. I have been stuck on this for ages. I read a lot of articles and watched videos but I still do not full understand this. Can you suggest any good book or other resource where I can use to become good at algorithms?

Comment: Hmmmm, I dont think this is something you can learn from books. You'll have to learn by doing it. Head over to codewars.com and start with the easy ones, it's real fun.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I will definitely checking it out. Regards.

Comment: Your solution fixes the bug, but not for the reason you describe. Rather, I'm pretty sure the OP's bug is simply caused by the fact that they're mixing DOM nodes and strings in the same array during the recursion, and that `arr[i].textContent` is undefined when `arr[i]` is a string.